# Nodes discovery on Google Cloud with Dynamic IP: Spring Boot Java application

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

Our app is based on Java Spring boot. And we totally based on Google cloud, where we have dynamic IP and our serve isntance will work behind Elastic load balance, where an instance may get spawned and get killed based on server resource consumptions.

None we these server instance can be assumed to have static IP.

**Looking for solution to connect different server instance with dynamic IP on Google Cloud.**

Answer (score 0):

Since 3.6, Hazelcast offers Discovery SPI to integrate external discovery mechanisms into the system. As a result there are many discovery plugins and you can implement your own. See the list of your options [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#discovery-mechanisms). Kubernetes might be helpful in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional info from what Sertug said,

There is also a Google Compute SPI that might be helpful, you can check it out here:

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-gcp

Also, here's a blog post (a little old but still valid):

https://blog.hazelcast.com/hazelcast-discovery-spi